# Best practise to handle Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException from Bean class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Am using Bean class to get/set value for the attributes. In some cases am gettig `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` error due to the value is null. What will be the best practice to handle null pointer exception when we get/set values from/to bean class.

Is that ternary operator is good to use or any other suggestions?

Please find the below line of code where am getting null pointer exception.

```
doc.setCatalog_title(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_title").toString());
```

Comment: Is `sourceAsMap` null Or is `sourceAsMap.get(..)` returning null? or is `doc` null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointer exception basic cause is that you are calling a method or variable from null variable i.e. a variable which is currently not holding reference of any object. So, the easy way to avoid it is assign that variable a reference on which subsequent tasks can be called

Now this can be handled in n no. of ways, out of which some basic ways are:

1. Using if condition

   ```
    if(doc!=null && sourceAsMap!=null && sourceAsMap.get("catalog_title")!=null)
        doc.setCatalog_title(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_title").toString());
   ```
2. Using ternary operator:

   ```
    doc = null == doc ? new Document():doc;
    doc.setCatalog_title(sourceAsMap!=null && sourceAsMap.get("catalog_title")!=null ? sourceAsMap.get("catalog_title").toString() : null);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Aman., I asked for Best Practice  for that i dont why i got some many negative votes. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava Preconditions (https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained), as it good practice to check preconditions of your class before executing it. As you can use `checkNotNull(T)`.

If you are expecting null in your system then instead of using a null check, use **Optional** class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html,

If you are using Java 7 then you can use **Optional** from **Guava** https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained